# PropertyChanged doesn't call its own getter

Tags: silverlight, propertychanged

I have some basic properties.  Behind the scenes I fill a `Lookup` with a Text-Value and the name of the properties to be affected.  So I have `CostUpdated, Cost`, `CostUpdated, CostSum`, and `CostUpdated, TotalSum`.  My expectation is that my Silverlight XAML Bindings for all three should hit the Getters, and so re-update the text fields when Cost is set.  So Cost is set, and the Getters should be called for all three.

```
public decimal Cost {
    get {
        return _Cost;
    }
    set {
        _Cost = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CostUpdated")
    }
}

public decimal CostSum {
    get {
        return _CostSum;
    }
    set {
        _CostSum = value;
    }
}

public decimal TotalSum {
    get {
        return _TotalSum;
    }
    set {
        _TotalSum = value;
    }
}

Lookup<string, string> DependentProperties;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    foreach (var prop in DependentProperties[property])
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

The foreach picks up all three values I registered.  All three appear to execute when I'm stepping through, but the getter of "Cost" is never hit.  I can't step into PropertyChangedEventArgs since it's system code, but something in there cancels out the execution and does not throw an exception.  The other two are hit as expected.

This is the kicker: If I turn off the Silverlight Debugger, it works fine.  Some of us know that having a debugger attached causes side effects such as cancelling infinite loops or over-analyzing.  But I don't want code that only works in a non-debugger world!!

Answer (score 0):

If you disable XAML binding debugging, the issue is gone.

Set `Binding.IsDebuggingEnabled = false;` (e.g in your app.xaml.cs)

Without an attached debugger the IsDebuggingEnabled flag is set to false, thus you don't have the problem when you run without an debugger.